# Multi-level wildcard (catch-all) DNS setup *.*.domain.com => one IP/CNAME

Tags: domain-name-system

It is well known that it is possible to configure a DNS server to do a "catch-all" resolving on a single subdomain level, such as `*.example.com. IN A x.x.x.x`, so that `anything.example.com` maps to a single IP/CNAME.

However, I need to set up an **at least "level-2" wildcard sub-subdomain catch-all** wildcard system so that `any.thing.example.com` or better, `item.of.any.level.under.example.com` will be resolved to a single IP.

Has anyone got this working?

Comment: I can just say it definitely *is* possible. You'll have to wait for someone competent to tell you *how*, though.

Comment: Yes, I belive it is. But I need an advice how to achieve this on common server software (BIND, Microsoft DNS server, etc.).

Comment: You should add the DNS software that you are using

Answer (score 7):

On any real DNS server a wildcard record will match one **or more** labels.

See section 4.3.3 of [RFC 1034](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034#section-4.3.3).

Answer (score 6):

Works in bind with just a record for `*.dig.foo.com`, it will grab anything under that domain. I.e. `dog.cat.dig.foo.com`

**Edit:**
This is a sample configuration file.

```
BIND 9.2.4 and the zone file content is 
$ORIGIN test.domain.com.
*          CNAME          proxyserver.domain.com.
$ORIGIN domain.com.
....
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, could you please give me a BIND version number and possibly and the contents of a zone file?

Answer (score 1):

We use multi level subdomains on our CDNs. In our DNS control panel (Zerigo) we just used *.ourcdn.com mapping to a CName of our CDN. Then we can use

node1.site1.ourcdn.com
node2.site1.ourcdn.com
node1.site2.ourcdn.com
node2.site2.ourcdn.com

I haven't had a chance to test this on BIND etc. but I'm fairly certain it will work the same in there, Zerigo responsds with

*.ourcdn.com. IN CNAME cdnsource.com